# How to display push notification in foreground even when the app is closed?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my current implementation, this works well when the app is opened but notification was not opening in foreground when the app is closed.

```
createNotificationListeners() {
    this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
        const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
            sound: 'default',
            show_in_foreground: true,
        })
        .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
        .setTitle(notification.title)
        .setBody(notification.body)
        .android.setChannelId('fcm_default_channel')
        .android.setSmallIcon('@mipmap/ic_launcher')
        .android.setColor('#000000')
        .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);

        firebase.notifications().displayNotification(localNotification)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });

    // set  channelId
    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
      "fcm_default_channel",
      "Firebase Alert",
      firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.High
    );
    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
}
```

I have this question already in [github](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2125) but haven't got enough response

Comment: That's impossible. You can just display a notification in foreground if the app is opened.

Comment: @Tim But when I use other applications like Gmail or mail application, Google pay, they show notifications even when the app is closed.. So was confused where I have gone wrong

Comment: What you mean is a background notification.

Comment: Sorry.. I think so.. let me try with background notifications and ill come back

Comment: @Tim still what sort of thing I am missing to get background notifications??